# PHP preg_replace: Conditionally insert whitespace

Tags: php, regex

In PHP I want to insert a white space after each `<` but only if there is no white space already.

I tried:

```
preg_replace('/<\S/', '< ', $data);
```

This works for a single `<` but if I have `<<` it does not work anymore.

Comment: That line replaces the character following a "<" by a space. For example, "<abc" becomes "< bc". Is this the desired functionality or should it become "< abc"?

Comment: No, I want to insert a whitespace if there is no whitespace already there after any '<'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Summoner pointed out, your current regex *replaces* the character after a `<` with a space rather than *inserting* one. Well, both problems (the replacement and the code not working on something like `<<`) can be fixed with one solution: [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Try this code:

```
preg_replace('/<(?!\s)/', '< ', $data);
```